# Error: The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly

Tags: ubuntu, electron, windows-subsystem-for-linux, chmod, suid

I'm sorry to just paste an error code, but I have no clue what else to try. I have looked at all the guides on this site, but nothing quite matches my issue. I am using an ubuntu subsystem on windows 10 for the project "Zettlr". Here is the error code I get when running 'yarn start'

```
The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly.
Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now.
You need to make sure that node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755.
Done in 17.85s.
```

I am trying to run this, but it wants me to change access and ownership. chmod has no effect (which I understand is due to the windows storage system) but I have no idea how to get this program to run correctly. I have also ran chown. From my stat check, the chmod mode for the file is 777, so it should be accessable anyway. Could anyone direct me to a guide for this, or explain what I can do?

Comment: Per https://github.com/Revolutionary-Games/Thrive/issues/749 it seems that running `sudo sysctl kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1` is the solution here. Whether this is a safe thing to do is unknown to me https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/209529/what-does-enabling-kernel-unprivileged-userns-clone-do. You may also be able to use `--no-sandbox` which also doesn't seem like a security improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the files you are working with are on NTFS volumes, mounted somewhere under `/mnt`. Move your project to a native Linux partition, for example under `$HOME`, `/var`, `/opt`, etc.

`chmod` and its friends (`chgrp`, `chown`) should all work 100% on native Linux volumes.

Comment: I only gave the one hard drive and it's on windows 10. Do those folders exist for me?

Comment: I did and I couldn't find it, and I thought they might not be there as it's all one hard drive and I thought the mounting was the same. Sorry I just got a bit confused, sorry. I'll have another look, thankyou.

Comment: What did you type to look? I am sure that if you go to a terminal and type `ls /` you will see those directories. Sounds like you need to learn basics about Linux. Any Linux tutorial video will explain this in the first 5 minutes.

Comment: Well, I often just use a normal Linux system, however I was just using the subsystem. I believed that the subsystem was just an interpreter for Linux commands to windows commands, however now I realise that there's more going on.
 Tomorrow I'll let you know how this goes. Thanks for your help =)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but when I move to those areas as I run yarn start, it breaks and says it cannot progress due to permission denied when trying to remove a directory. I realise that's because it must use sudo, however, the program also won't run in a sandbox if I use sudo, so I must find a native Linux directory that doesn't have file deletion protection.

Any ideas?

Comment: Here is the error if it helps

```
An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
[Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/home/tlpap/Zettlr/.webpack/main'] {
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'rmdir',
  path: '/home/tlpap/Zettlr/.webpack/main'
}

Electron Forge was terminated. Location:
{}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: You can use `sudo` to modify the permissions for a directory. This again sounds like you are unaware of basic knowledge about Linux. Again I suggest you take a few hours and work through a Linux 101 tutorial. Don't just quickly skim a summary article, learn by doing... type along. Otherwise, you won't progress.

Comment: I think you're right. I have used Linux for 4 years for Uni, however every task has just been to write c++ code and run it in terminal, and every question I have had about linux has been an individual google search and copy-paste solution. I never really took the time to learn linux as an operating system from scratch, or how it differences to Windows. I think i'll do that now, thanks for your help =)

Comment: Go for it, you will be glad you did for years and years. This is one of life's essential skills, like using a telephone or knowing how to drive.